rvest web scraping returning empty xml_nodeset
I am trying to scrape data using rvest but it's been a while and I cannot complete what would seem to be a simple task. I've tried various html and css elements to pull the data, but keep getting the output {xml_nodeset (0)}.
The code I've been using, for example, is:
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.helmet.beam.vt.edu/bicycle-helmet-ratings.html"
webpage <- read_html(url)
webpage %>% html_nodes("span.helmet-name")

I'd expect a list beginning with the bike names that are highlighted when using this class with selectorgadget:

I also did customize this class in selectorgadget, as the default option was only b, which might have been ok but didn't seem as specific. I just looked at the code and found the classname.

All that data is loaded via javascript. Check out the experimental read_html_live function instead or use a package like RSelenium if you need something to run the javascript for you. You could also try reverse engineering the HTTP calls to see if you can extract the data directly. The selectorgadget looks at the current DOM which is different than the source code that basic scraping would see.

It looks like the data you probably want is in the file https://www.helmet.beam.vt.edu/js/bicycleData.js. Sadly the data is embedded in javascript code rather than plain JSON data. But you could probably manipulate it to be proper JSON.

@MrFlick Thanks for the recommendation about read_html_live. I was able to use that to extract the relevant information with different html tags and css classes.

As that page loads the dataset to bicycleDataRaw js variable:
var bicycleDataRaw = [
    {
        brand: "Specialized",
        model: "Tactic 4",
        score: 8.554,
        rating: 5,
        cost: "$110",
        style: "Mountain",
        date: "2021",
        photo: "specialized-tactic-4.jpg",
        certifications: "CPSC",
        low: 2.019,
        high: 6.535
    }, ...
]

, we can pull that from chromote session as R list.
Evaluate javascript in chromote session through rvest::LiveHTML object that was returned by rvest::read_html_live() :
library(rvest)
s <- read_html_live("https://www.helmet.beam.vt.edu/bicycle-helmet-ratings.html")
s$session$Runtime$evaluate("bicycleDataRaw", returnByValue = TRUE)$result$value |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows() 

#> # A tibble: 241 × 11
#>    brand   model score rating cost  style date  photo certifications   low  high
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Specia… Tact…  8.55      5 $110  Moun… 2021  spec… CPSC            2.02  6.54
#>  2 Sweet … Trai…  8.69      5 $180  Moun… 2021  swee… CPSC            2.03  6.66
#>  3 Specia… Mode   8.80      5 $120  Urban 2021  spec… CPSC            2.42  6.38
#>  4 Fox     Drop…  8.85      5 $200  Moun… 2020  fox-… CPSC            2.30  6.55
#>  5 Giant   Rev …  9.12      5 $65   Road  2021  gian… CPSC            2.20  6.92
#>  6 Lazer   G1 M…  9.23      5 $240  Road  2020  laze… CPSC            2.40  6.83
#>  7 Bontra… Rall…  9.35      5 $150  Moun… 2019  bont… CPSC            2.34  7.01
#>  8 Specia… Alig…  9.55      5 $50   Mult… 2020  spec… CPSC            2.95  6.6 
#>  9 Lazer   Toni…  9.85      5 $80   Road  2021  laze… CPSC            2.56  7.29
#> 10 Troy L… A2 M…  9.99      5 $179  Moun… 2019  troy… CPSC            2.52  7.46
#> # ℹ 231 more rows

